# An error connecting to Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am working on an Android app where I have a Spinner, and on the base of which item I choose, the app will read in text file number 1 or number 2, etc... I have written a code, but when I run it on my device, it says that "The application has stopped unexpectedly".

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner spinner;
String textSource = "";
TextView textMsg;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textmsg);
spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
URL textUrl;
    String stringText = "";
    try {
        textUrl = new URL(textSource);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));
        //ISO-8859-1
        String StringBuffer;
        //String stringText = "";
        while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringText += StringBuffer;

        }

        bufferReader.close();




        textMsg.setText(stringText);
        //textMsg.setText(string123);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        textMsg.setText(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        textMsg.setText(e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(Text.equals("list 1")) {

        textSource = "path/to/textfile 1";

    }       
    else if(Text.equals("list 2")){
        textSource = "path/to/textfile 2";

   }    
   else {

   }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

How should I solve this problem?

Thanks for helping

Comment: StringIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use

```
String Text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

instead of

```
String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

**So that it becomes** :

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
        long arg3) {

    String Text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(Text.equals("list 1")) {    
        textSource = "path/to/textfile 1";    
    }       
    else if(Text.equals("list 2")){
        textSource = "path/to/textfile 2";    
    }    
    else {    
    }  

    // then put your URL code here as follows
    URL textUrl;
    String stringText = "";
    try {
        textUrl = new URL(textSource);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));
        //ISO-8859-1
        String StringBuffer;            

        while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringText += StringBuffer;    
        }

        bufferReader.close();  
        textMsg.setText(stringText);
        //textMsg.setText(string123);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
        textMsg.setText(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        textMsg.setText(e.toString());
    }   

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling **textUrl = new URL(textSource);** inside oncreate() method textSource will be always " ". Better create a method and pass the new textSource value based on onItemSelected .

Sample for Your reference: **By Default Link1 will be passed**

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
        long arg3) {
    String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (Text.equals("list 1")) {
        Method("path/to/textfile 1");

    } else if (Text.equals("list 2")) {
        Method("path/to/textfile 2");

    } else {

    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Method :

```
public void Method(String textSource) {

    URL textUrl;
    String stringText = "";
    try {
        textUrl = new URL(textSource);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));
        // ISO-8859-1
        String StringBuffer;
        // String stringText = "";
        while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringText += StringBuffer;

        }

        bufferReader.close();

        textMsg.setText(stringText);
        // textMsg.setText(string123);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        textMsg.setText(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        textMsg.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a code, how do you mean that because I'm just a beginner and I have tried to do this, but somehow I failed.